# Read CSV File In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm uploading and then reading the CSV file but I'm facing an issue while splitting it, so basically, column names in CSV contain `','` so when I'm going to split the columns with `','` so I don't get the full column value, please suggest me some proper way for it. Thanks

```
const readCsv = (file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const filetext = reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        const data = e.target.result;
        let parsedata = [];

        let newLinebrk = data.split('\n');
        for (let i = 0; i < newLinebrk.length; i++) {
            parsedata.push(newLinebrk[i].split(','));
        }
        console.log("parsedData: ", parsedata);
    });
};
```

CSV:

```
column 1   column2                    
test       lorem, ipsum, dummy/text
```

after splitting:

```
['test', 'lorem', 'ipsum', 'dummy/text']
```

so by doing that I'm unable to get a proper column name that contains a comma in string.

Comment: May I know if exploring existing solutions, such as [csv-reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-reader), can be considered? Also, is it okay to consider changing the delimiter to some other character (may be ^ or ~) instead of comma?

Comment: @jsN00b don't wanna use any 3rd party library

Comment: Issue is that within the code, how does one differentiate which comma is the delimiter (indicating end of a column) and which comma is part of the cell (text)?

Comment: yes, that is my question :)

Comment: @jsN00b can you share an example in react with csv-reader?

Comment: [LMGTFY](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=csv-reader+reactjs+example+codesandbox) and, [here is one example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-csv-reader-vtull)

Comment: @jsN00b this is also doing the same, splits my original column value

Comment: You need to check for values between quotes. In any case, this question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/example-javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I used [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) which fulfills my all requirements.

```
const readCsv = (file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        const data = e.target.result;
        Papaparse.parse(data, {
            complete: function (results) {
                console.log("results: ", results.data);
            },
        });
    });
};
```